# How can I change the PS3's startup menu page?

Tags: ps3

Following the demise of my "fat" Playstation 3 console I got myself a new, slim, one.

After logging in with my user on my original console, I would end up in the Game menu, which was very convenient for launching the disc currently in the console while still waiting for my TV to turn itself on.

On my new console, however, I always end up on the PlaystationNetwork menu. I imagine there is some sort of setting somewhere that I need to change, but I am hard pressed to find it and would appreciate some instructions.

So where is that setting hiding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you end up on Network or PlaystationNetwork menu?
If you always start on the What's new menu, you can change this in *Settings > System Settings > Display [What's New]* and set it to off. [Reference in the manual](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/settings/displaynew.html).